# SQLAlchemy two identically named primary keys that are also foreign

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlcemy in a Flask app to migrate an old MySQL database to a new one whilst performing some cleaning and such en route. I don't control the schema on the target, and as such I'm bound their frustrating schema and manner of declaring column names and relationships.

My models look thus:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class EntryTitle(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entry_title'

    entry_id = Column('entry_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(155))

class EntryData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entry_data' 

    entry_id = Column('entry_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = Column('body', String(255))
```

I need to relate the second to the first, joined on that `entry_id` column, and I'm unsure of the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your primary key as a foreign key, then SQLAlchemy will figure out the relation by itself while doing join:

```py
class EntryTitle(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entry_title'
    entry_id = Column('entry_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(155))
    # Assuming this is a one-to-one relationship, so setting uselist to False.
    entry_data = relationship('EntryData', backref='entry_title',
                              uselist=False)

class EntryData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entry_data'
    # Simply define this primary key as a foreign key to entry_title table.
    entry_id = Column('entry_id', Integer, ForeignKey('entry_title.entry_id'),
                      primary_key=True)
    body = Column('body', String(255))

# Add new objects to a session.
entry_title = EntryTitle(title='Foo')                                            
entry_title.entry_data = EntryData(body='Bar')                                   
session.add(entry_title)                                                         
session.commit()

# Query whole models.
q1 = session.query(EntryTitle, EntryData).join(EntryData)
# Or just the columns you need.
q2 = session.query(EntryTitle.title, EntryData.body).\
    join(EntryData).\
    filter(EntryTitle.entry_id == 42)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's my fault for not using my code verbatim. I'm actually using the ORM with `declarative_base`. I've adjusted my example, but I guess it's safe to assume the `ForeignKey` / `primary_key` combo will still work?

Comment: Yes, you're correct about using `ForeignKey`. I updated my answer as well.

Comment: and how would I add a new EntryData? I'll know the old entry_id, but that can't be re-used in the new one since it's auto incremented. I was hoping it would be something like

    title = ChannelTitle({'title': 'My title'})
    data = ChannelData({'body': 'My body', entry_id=title.entry_id})

    db_session.add(title)
    db_session.add(data)
    db_session.commit()

Comment: I saw your edit to my answer (which was rejected) and I understand that you've figured it out by yourself, but I'm going to update my code so that others could benefit from it.